# Select the oldest from join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making my own archive system. Here is how it looks so far. I have following SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    serial_number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    catalog_number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE entities (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE entities_relations (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    entity_id int NOT NULL,
    row_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Each entity where table_name is "items" has at least one item matched via entities_relations. entities_relations shows how many relations are between one entity and items. After saving an item it saves a new Item which is a copy of the previous one and adds a relation. Copies (archive items) don't create a new entity, they create only relation. The oldest relation is the original item.

The following SQL syntax shows me items list. It's wrong because it shows me all items, even if they are archived. I would like to display only the original ones. How can I change it to be  able to display only original ones and ignore archives?

```
SELECT 
    items.*, 
FROM 
    items 
LEFT JOIN entities_relations ON 
    entities_relations.row_id = items.id 
LEFT JOIN entities ON 
    entities.id = entities_relations.entity_id 
WHERE 
    entities.name = 'items' 
ORDER BY 
    entities.id DESC, 
    entities_relations.entity_id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Move the entities.name condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I'm a bit confused on what your data model has to do with "archiving".

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output as well